# Sending a string using a bundle

Tags: android

I have two Activities, say Activity A and Activity B, which are both dialogs. When I click on a button on Activity A it triggers Activity B. When I'm on Activity B, I click on a button, which sends a string to Activity A by using a bundle, which Activity A receives. When I go back to Activity B to send another string,it causes Activity A which is currently behind it to force close and not send the string. I'm not sure why this is.

Your help will be most appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: You should provide the stack trace in the logcat to help us (and you) figure out your trouble.

Comment: Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) an answer if one of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

If one of you activity is more central than the other, you should use startActivityForResult in it. It will call the second one, and one the second one finished it can communicate results and extra in a bundle too.

This model looks cleaner, at least more standard, than a loop between activities. Although what you do and the way you do it should also work.

Btw, your activities may have a dialog theme but they are not dialogs, no ?

Regards, 
 Stéphane